# Xcode 8 recommend me to change the min iOS Deployment Target from 7.1 to 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

When I use the Xcode 8 beta(8S128d) to open my project,it recommend me to change the min iOS Deployment Target to 8.0 instead 7.1.
And I found that there is no option less than 8.0 in the iOS Deployment Target list.

[image: Deployment Target]

So, does it mean that I no longer need to adjust my project for iOS 7.x or less?

Answer (score 56):

I think if the app has many users who are using iOS 7, it would be necessary to adjust project to support iOS 7.

I have tried build, debug, archive with deployment target 7.0 using Xcode 8 Beta(8S128d). 

All succeeded. Also successfully export and install the ipa on my iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2(11D257)) .

I did the followings to change my project deployment target to 7.0 and remove the suggestion warning.

1. Manually input "7.0" in the "iOS Deployment Target" text box.
   [image: Manually change iOS deployment target]
2. Uncheck the "Update iOS Deployment Target" and press "Perform Changes" / "Done" button,
   then the recommended suggestion warning will disappear.
   [image: Recommended Suggestion]

**Edit**:

#### Make Xcode 8.x debug your apps on iOS 7.x devices.

1. You need **Xcode 7.x** . You can download it from [Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).
2. **Open** Finder, and **go** to "**Xcode 7.x**.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/**DeviceSupport**/".
3. **Copy** "**7.0**" and "**7.1**" folders and **paste** them to "**Xcode 8.x**.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/**DeviceSupport**/".

[image]

4. **Open** "**Xcode 8.x**.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/**SDKSettings.plist**"

[image]

5. **Add** values, "**7.0**" and "**7.1**", to key, "Root/DefaultProperties/**DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SUGGESTED_VALUES**", according to the following screenshot.

[image]

6. **Restart Xcode 8.x**.
7. Now you can choose "**7.0**" or "**7.1**" in the "**iOS Deployment Target**" text box list and debug your apps on iOS 7.x devices.

Comment: Interesting.  This is an unsupported configuration according to Apple.  I'm surprised this works in the beta.

Comment: In order to check if it's a feasible workaround I guess we should upload the IPA file to iTunes connect, waiting the feedback after processing the binary file.

Comment: Using the Xcode 8 GM, I manually changed my deployment target to 7.0, my app was approved and released, and users with iOS 7 are able to install it. So I can confirm this solution works.

Comment: To test with iOS 7, after archive the app into Organizer (same step prepare for upload to App Store), open Organizer, on right side panel, click "Export...".  Then select "Save for Development Deployment" and go thru the dialogs.  Select "Export one app for all compatible devices".  You will get an IPA file.  Connect your iOS 7 device, open "Devices" in Xcode.  Then drag the IPA onto your iOS 7 device.

Comment: What if "Update to recommend settings" not at all showing?

Comment: @himanth In some cases, "Update to recommend settings" warning will be shown when your project's settings version is lower than Xcode version. If it is not shown, skip the step 2.

Comment: @Leon Excellent work around, Thanks! What if I want to test my app in device running iOS 10.2 and Xcode 8.0?

Comment: @Nij I have no idea. Maybe only upgrade Xcode to 8.2 :)

Answer (score 5):

The minimum deployment target with Xcode 8 is iOS 8.  To support target the iOS SDK 7.x and below, use Xcode 7.

If you try to use a deployment target of iOS 7.x or below, Xcode will suggest you change your target to iOS 8:

[image: Xcode Warning]

Comment: If you run Mac OS Sierra you cannot start Xcode 7.x as it crashes on launch due to a missing library.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has changed so much since iOS 7 until now.  The easiest way of not having to deal with backward compatibility is to make the old OS's obsolete.  <s>So you have 2 choices.  You can leave the setting as is and deal with the warning message,</s> or you can change the setting and not support iOS 7 or lower any longer.  There are pros and cons to each...

<s>Leave the setting:  If you chose to leave the Min OS setting as is your app will have a larger user base.  But since new OS adoption rate is very very high this is not as much of an issue with iOS devices as it would be with Android devices.  You would also have to deal with supporting iOS 7.  That means that if you decide to use any new features not available in iOS 7 you would have to deal with the iOS 7 case.  Possible app crashes, inconsistent UI, etc...</s>

Change the setting:  If you chose to change the setting then you no longer have to support iOS 7 (you can create much simpler and more consistent code with new features).  You also slightly shrink your customer base (very very slightly).

It's up to you what you would like to do, but really all devices that can run 7 can also run 8.  So if they want your app they can just upgrade OS's and be fine (not like the iPad 1 that stopped at iOS 5).  My customers are all large businesses that need to run through lots of red tape to upgrade their fleet of devices.  So I have to support iOS 7 (for now, xCode 8 may give me the sway to force those who haven't to upgrade).

Comment: `You can leave the setting as is and deal with the warning message` but Xcode 8 does not support building for the iOS 7 SDK, you can't just leave this warning alone.  Your app won't build or run on iOS 7.

Comment: @JAL Good to know.  I will change my answer.

Comment: Not all devices running iOS7 can Update to iOS 8. The iPhone 4 (without s) is not able to run iOS 8.

Comment: Also, devices running iOS 7 can't actually update to iOS 8, they have to update to iOS 9 and soon will have to update to iOS 10. This creates a problem for users with older devices that technically support the latest iOS version but exhibit poor performance with it.

Comment: @Putz1103 I have just built an app with a deployment target of 7.0 (and therefore had this warning), but it did built. It was signed for InHouse distribution and runs on a iOS 7.1.3 test phone and as far as I can see everything works fine. I just don't know if the app is submittable to the App Store or not.

Comment: Building with a deployment target of 6.0 in Xcode 8.3.2 works fine. Built IPAs can be installed on pre iOS 8.0 devices and they run correctly. These builds are now live on the app store and work correctly. You can un-score out the leave the setting part as this is totally valid. The only thing is you can't debug on a device below iOS 8.0 with Xcode 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fiddle with XCode just update your project file for iOS 6 or 7.
Right click .xcodeproj choose "Show package contents" and edit project.pbxproj in favorite text editor.
Search for IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 7.0;