# Xcode 8 / Swift 3 and installing apps on iPhone 4 running iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

Can apps created with Xcode 8 / Swift 3 be installed on an iPhone 4 device running iOS 7? Does Xcode 8 / Swift 3 support all iOS 7 devices?

Is there specific documentation detailing what is and isn't compatible that answers this question?

It appears Xcode 8 doesn't seem to ship with an iPhone 4/4S simulator. Currently my experience is that apps created with Xcode 7 / Swift 2 can be installed successfully on iPhone 4S running iOS 7.

EDIT: I've now done some testing with "interesting" results:
[Do Xcode 8 Swift 3 apps run on iOS 7 successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414469/do-xcode-8-swift-3-apps-run-on-ios-7-successfully)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817554/xcode-8-recommend-me-to-change-the-min-ios-deployment-target-from-7-1-to-8-0

Answer (score 2):

You can select the minimum version of iOS your app will run on, so as long as you have iOS 7 or earlier selected, it should run on an iPhone 4/4S that's on iOS 7.

If you have an iPhone 4/4S on iOS 7 with you, try plugging it in and debugging on it.
I am quite certain it should work.

EDIT: As long as iOS 7 is still available as a deployment target in the XCode Beta, I'm yet to try it out, sorry!

Comment: Thanks. I can track down an iPhone 4S but an iPhone 4 is harder to come by.

Comment: I think you cant have deployment target less than 8.0 with swift 3.