# update Alamofire in podfile error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, watchkit, watch

After migrating from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3, I have found these error on compile time:

```
Analyzing dependencies

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

change target:

```
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search? q=File+exists+%40+dir_s_mkdir+-+%2FUsers%2Fusers%2FMyApp-ios%2FPods%2FTarget+Support+Files%2FAlamofire-iOS10.0&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
```

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

```
Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new
```

xcode:

```
The file “Alamofire-watchOS.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Users/nameusers/MyApp/Pods/Target Support Files/Alamofire-watchOS/Alamofire-watchOS.xcconfig)

Alamofire-watchOS will not be code signed because its settings don't specify a development team.

error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support       Files/Alamofire-watchOS/Alamofire-watchOS.modulemap': Error   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Alamofire-watchOS.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/nameusers/MyApp/Pods/Target Support Files/Alamofire-watchOS/Alamofire-watchOS.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff89768f8e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/Alamofire-watchOS/Alamofire-watchOS.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Alamofire-watchOS.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/nameusers/MyApp/Pods/Target Support Files/Alamofire-watchOS/Alamofire-watchOS.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff895163940 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Comment: Your project is supporting a older iOS, you need to change the deployment target to iOS 9.0+. If you want to use older versions, use older Alamofire.

Comment: platform :ios, '10.0' In PODfile

Answer (score 1):

[According to these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067678/swift-3-ios-compatibility) [related StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414469/do-xcode-8-swift-3-apps-run-on-ios-7-successfully), Swift 3 appears to only work on iOS 8 and newer.

It sounds like you need to update your `Podfile` (and your own app's project settings) to have a higher minimum deployment target.  e.g.:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

This means you won't be able to support older versions of iOS any more.