# iOS: Using Swift 4 when targeting iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Swift 4 is adding some really cool features, like strongly typed keypaths and [JSON encoding/decoding using `Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

I would like to use these new features while still targeting iOS 9 and above.

As far as I understand, Swift language version is not bound to a version of iOS, as opposite to Foundation framework, for example. However, I can't find any info if that's correct.

Can I use Swift 4 when targeting iOS older than 11?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, just like with Swift 1, Swift 2 and Swift 3, **you can use Swift 4 with any version of iOS 7 and above**.

See this similar question for Swift 3: [Xcode 8 / Swift 3 and installing apps on iPhone 4 running iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218446/xcode-8-swift-3-and-installing-apps-on-iphone-4-running-ios-7)
See this similar question for Swift 2: [Swift 2.0 minimum system version requirement (deployment target)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825638/swift-2-0-minimum-system-version-requirement-deployment-target)

---

Note: as iOS 11 is dropping support for 32-bit, you will only be able to use iOS 11 from an arm64 slice (that is, from iPhone 5S and up). [Source](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_3/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_9_beta_3.pdf):

> iOS 11 no longer supports armv7 or armv7s (32-bit). If an iOS target has an iOS Deployment
>   Target of 11, then it will not build for 32-bit. iOS targets with an iOS Deployment Target earlier
>   than 11 will still build for 32-bit by default. (32163517)

Comment: Do you have a link some Apple doc showing that Xcode 9 will not be able to target arm7? I've heard this, but have not seen it documented.

Comment: According to the Xcode 9 release notes, it's actually iOS 11 that's dropping support for 32 bit apps, not the Xcode. Therefore, you should be able to target pre-iPhone 5S devices when building in Xcode 9: "iOS 11 no longer supports armv7 or armv7s (32-bit). If an iOS target has an iOS Deployment Target of 11, then it will not build for 32-bit. iOS targets with an iOS Deployment Target earlier than 11 will still build for 32-bit by default. (32163517)"

Comment: Xcode Release Notes: https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=xcode-9-beta-rn Note that you need to sign in with your dev id in order to see that page.