# What is the highest version of Xcode that supports iOS 6.0 as the deployment target?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an iOS app for iOS 6.0 and higher. Now, after updating Xcode from Mac App Store, I am told that "An iOS Deployment Target earlier than 8.0 is not supported by this version of Xcode.". So, it seems that I need to use another version of Xcode to develop this app.

I can download other versions of Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/. What is the highest version of Xcode that supports iOS 6.0 as the deployment target?(I just mean the deployment target, not the capability of installing iOS 6.0 simulator.) I don't want to download many Xcode versions to find that.

Comment: Don't support discontinued iOS versions. Always use the latest version of IDE (Xcode).

Answer (score 1):

You can use latest Xcode for this do not select `deployment target` from dropdown, just manually input "6.0" in the "iOS Deployment Target" text box. 
For more details you can go through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37829427/5148089).

I have also upload one of my [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/homavo-tools-for-ebay-sellers/id1068090751?mt=8) that use iOS 7.0 from latest Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6 is supported in Xcode 7.x .

My suggestion is that,you may need to provide support for just 2 of previous versions of iOS 10, ie. iOS 8 and 9. If you take a look at the usage [graph](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/), it is evident that only 6% are using versions earlier than 9. That too, will have major contributions from iOS 8 and 7.