# How to change my deployment target to 5.0 on Xcode 7.3.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to change my deployment target to 5.0.But in my Xcode **General settings -> Deployment target** shows until 6.0 only. I can’t find 5.0 option in my deployment target option.Please go through the following image. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: You can write 5.0 to it but the only proper way to do it would be to install an older Xcode. Apple doesn't want you to support older iOSes because reasons :/

Comment: You should install older Xcode.

Comment: You have tagged your question with [swift], but Swift is only available on iOS 7 and later.

Comment: thats my mistake..I updated it.You have any idea about this?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/37829427/1187415, you can manually enter a version number in that field. (I cannot tell right now if that works or has any negative consequences.)