# available Xamarin 64bit iOS SDK versions

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin iOS project, the only SDK I am able to target is 10.2 and 10.3.  However, iOS7 is the first 64-bit iOS, and to capture users that haven't upgraded the OS on their 5S, I need to target iOS7.  What do I need to do to make 7.x appear in the dropdown?  Or is that even necessary?

[image]

I modified my Info.plist to...

[image]

Is this all that is needed to support the lower iOS versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, only need to change in Info.plist on the minimum iOS version to support.
It is fine to use the latest SDK to compile.

However, do you really still want to support iOS 7 user? Current stats in [AppStore](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) is iOS10  - 86%, iOS9 - 11% and earlier version only 3% of users.

Normally in iOS we only support the latest 2-3 versions.

Comment: Appreciate the insight. This app is for business customers, and many haven't updated their OS (ever).

Comment: As a comment. Apple requires all new app-submissions to be build against iOS 8. If I remember correctly for two years now.

Comment: the guidelines is to build against with the new SDK. In this case, it is build against iOS 10.3. It is only the minimum support version is changed.

Comment: Found this post that maybe you can give it a try to have better support on iOS7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817554/xcode-8-recommend-me-to-change-the-min-ios-deployment-target-from-7-1-to-8-0